# DART User state for http call

Tags: flutter, dart

In some of the other languages I've used you can pass a user state into a http call then you get that user state returned on the callback. Does dart support this at all or would it have to be done manually?

Comment: what do you mean by "pass a user state into a http call "?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find an answer of how to do this with the http call in Dart, but I did find a package called DIO that has advanced functionality and wraps the http.

They have a parameter called extra that I could use to pass the state into the call and receive it on the response.